# error occurred during installing packages from YAML exported from another Conda environment on the same linux

Tags: conda

I exported an YAML file by using `conda env export > environment.yml`. Then I created a new
enviroment and activated it. Then I used `conda env update -f environment.yml` to install packages.
After successfully installation for several packages, the following error shown:

```py
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 819, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 74, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_update.py", line 126, in execute
        installer.install(prefix, specs, args, env)
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/installers/conda.py", line 39, in install
        unlink_link_transaction.execute()
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 223, in execute
        self.verify()
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 46, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 200, in verify
        self.prepare()
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 192, in prepare
        stp.remove_specs, stp.update_specs)
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 282, in _prepare
        mkdir_p(transaction_context['temp_dir'])
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/disk/__init__.py", line 60, in mkdir_p
        makedirs(path)
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 221, in makedirs
        mkdir(name, mode)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/.condatmp'
```

Comment: Have you checked what the permissions are on the folder in question? (`/home/user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/.condatmp`) Have you tried ensuring you have write permissions to it?

Comment: let me check. thanks.